# PivotItem element Animation

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a question regarding making pivotItem animations.
I'm using PivotItem as a control rather than a page.

I have few images in the ItemTemplate which i would like to animate

```
   <Pivot.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="CardsShuffle">
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="20" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" Storyboard.TargetName="Card3"  d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="-20" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" Storyboard.TargetName="Card1" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="-20.833" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Card1" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="-1.667" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Card1" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    </Storyboard>
            </Pivot.Resources>
```

And the pivot structure itself

```
            <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="10"
                                   FontSize="10"
                                   Text="{Binding PackName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Tapped="PivotItemSelected">
                        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Name="MyGrid">
                                <Image Name="Card3" Source="/Data/Images/img_test.png" MaxHeight="350">
                                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform CenterY="250" CenterX="90" />
                                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                                </Image>

                                <Image Name="Card2" Source="/Data/Images/img_test.png" MaxHeight="350">
                                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform Rotation="0"/>
                                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                                </Image>
                                <Image Name="Card1" Source="/Data/Images/img_test.png" MaxHeight="350" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform/>
                                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                                </Image>
                                <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Content="Animate"></Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
```

First of all i have a question regarding binding. I cannot find or figure out how to handle binding the child element instead of defining a name ( which works in grid but nor pivot).
Tried using Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName= PacksPivot, Path= '???'
but can't find a proper solution.

Second of all i want the animation to be triggered  x - seconds after PivotSelectedIndex changed otherwise i wanna have the initial state.

Any tips on the problem?

Comment: So you just want to flip some stuff around and nudge it a bit on the X,Y? The first part I don't really understand what you're asking, what's PacksPivot? and what do you mean by binding the child element? Maybe just a quick mock visual of what you want to accomplish would communicate it simpler. The second part, you can just append a `BeginTime` to the storyboard element itself for your delay after firing it off. Being a Friday and about to leave work cant promise a quick response either way.

Comment: Hey,Let me show you the structure
page -> grid -> stackpanel -> pivot with elements (PacksPivot). I want the binded elements to have animations (some rotations and nudges x,y) after some time delay. I want to identify elements by the 'child' property cause i think name wouldn't work with the binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i've solved it :)

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                            <Grid.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard x:Name="CardsShuffle">
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="20" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)"  Storyboard.TargetName="Card3"  d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="-20" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" Storyboard.TargetName="Card1" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="-20.833" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Card1" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="-1.667" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Card1" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </Grid.Triggers>
```

Names actualy work and i used event triggers to start the animations.